# Fourier transform of the integral with variable upper limit

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I have the following function

$$g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t f(t')dt'.$$

And I want to calculate the Fourier transform

$$G(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt.$$

Is there any way to proceed?

Comment: As written you would have that $f'(t)=f(t)$ which is solved by $f(t) = C e^t$

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: Compute the Fourier transform of $g'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that $g(t)=(f*H)(t)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function, and using the convolution theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{g\}&=\mathscr{F}\{f*H\}\\\\
&=\mathscr{F}\{f\}\mathscr{F}\{H\}\\\\
&=F(\omega)\left(\pi \delta(\omega)-\frac{i}{\omega}\right)\\\\&=\pi F(0)\delta(\omega)+\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}
\end{align}$$

And we are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(t')dt' \implies g(t)=F(t)-\lim_{n \rightarrow -\infty} F(n)$$

$$\therefore g(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt -\lim_{n \rightarrow -\infty} F(n) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega t}dt$$

Comment: I see you attended CSU.  My daughter received her MS in toxicology there and is a student in the CSU VET school currently.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an improper integral. That's why the limit is necessary. $f$ certainly has a family of antiderivatives but only up to a constant which is gotten rid of by having a definite integral, right? Glad to hear about your daughter, the vet school at CSU is world class.

Comment: Well, what you have doesn't really lead to anything more than just a double integral (implicitly through an antiderivative of $f$).  Thank you for your kind words.  I just LinkedIn with you.